# Разбить число на разряды и собрать массив из этих разрядов

Tags: c#

На входе - число, например: `int n = 1234567890;`
Нужно получить `string [] s = {'1', '234', '567', '890'};`
Это может быть и числовой массив, не суть. `int [] t = {1, 234, 567, 890};`
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как лучше это реализовать?

Answer (score 4):

```
int n = 1234567890;
var stack = new Stack<int>();
while(n > 0) {
    stack.Push(n % 1000);
    n = n/1000; 
}   
foreach(var i in stack) Console.WriteLine(i);
```

Вывод

```
1
234
567
890
```

Comment: Писал то же самое, забавно :)

Comment: @МаксЖуков мысли сходятся :)